# why does 2 statements with limits using unions does not acquire all records?

Tags: mysql, limit, union

I have a 2 statements with limits and union, but when I run the statement I only get the number of results that defined to the highest limit. I thought I would get X results from statement 1 plus Y results from statement 2. This did not occur. Why is that?

Here is the query example:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE X > 100 LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE X < 100 LIMIT 3;
```

The query above returns 3 results. However in this simple example I wanted 2 results + 3 results (5 results altogether).

If I modified the query like so I got the 5 results, but this query below appears misleading:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE X > 100 LIMIT 2
UNION
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE X < 100 LIMIT 5;
```

I found that by wrapping each statement in another statement resolved this. Here is how the final statement appears:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE X > 100 LIMIT 2
)query1
UNION
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE X < 100 LIMIT 3
)query2;
```

Thanks to anyone that can explain why behaviour of the initial two statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless parenthesis are used, the final `ORDER BY` and/or `LIMIT` clauses are applied to the query as a whole "outside/after" the union.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: great explanation. So if the lower limit is used as the secondary limit the result would be that of the lower limit? I am going to attempt the examples posted above where each query is enclosed in (). I would like to simplify the query. :)

Comment: The lower limit is applied to the UNIONed result. The official doc I linked shows how it is interpreted when parenthesis are not used just below the section chepner quoted in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html:

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Your example works. The explanation was not as clear as the one I selected. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your LIMIT in your first example is applied to the entire outer query. I've added some parentheses to make what's happening implicitly more obvious.

```
(SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE X > 100 LIMIT 2
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE X < 100) 
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. The explanation was lacking.